# Remove line from JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, integer, jtextarea

I have a `JTextArea` that is filled with numbers with no duplicates. There is an add and remove button. I have programmed the add button, but I am struggling with programming the remove button. I know how to remove the number from the array, but I'm not sure how to remove the number from the text area.

How do I remove a line from a text area that contains a certain number?

Extra notes:
The only input is integers.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for `JList` (rather than `JTextArea`). Then you'd simply need to remove the integer from the list model.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I swear I was typing my answer *before* you posted this. But I obviously agree 100%.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ah.. the advantages of going for a swift comment as opposed to a fuller answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where you ask how to fix a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider using a JList and not a JTextArea. You can easily rig it up to look just like a JTextArea, but with a JList, you can much more easily remove an item such as a line by removing it from its model.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class NumberListEg extends JPanel {
    private static final int VIS_ROW_COUNT = 10;
    private static final int MAX_VALUE = 10000;
    private DefaultListModel<Integer> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<Integer> numberList = new JList<>(listModel);
    private JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, MAX_VALUE, 1));
    private JButton addNumberButton = new JButton(new AddNumberAction());

    public NumberListEg() {
        JPanel spinnerPanel = new JPanel();
        spinnerPanel.add(spinner);
        JPanel addNumberPanel = new JPanel();
        addNumberPanel.add(addNumberButton);

        JPanel removeNumberPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton removeNumberButton = new JButton(new RemoveNumberAction());
        removeNumberPanel.add(removeNumberButton);

        JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        // gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
        eastPanel.add(spinner, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        eastPanel.add(addNumberButton, gbc);
        eastPanel.add(removeNumberButton, gbc);
        // eastPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue(), gbc);

        numberList.setVisibleRowCount(VIS_ROW_COUNT);
        numberList.setPrototypeCellValue(1234567);
        numberList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        JScrollPane listPane = new JScrollPane(numberList);
        listPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(listPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    private class AddNumberAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AddNumberAction() {
            super("Add Number");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_A);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int value = (int) spinner.getValue();
            if (!listModel.contains(value)) {
                listModel.addElement(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private class RemoveNumberAction extends AbstractAction {
        public RemoveNumberAction() {
            super("Remove Number");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_R);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Integer selection = numberList.getSelectedValue();
            if (selection != null) {
                listModel.removeElement(selection);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        NumberListEg mainPanel = new NumberListEg();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gui");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can not be remove from the array,you can to make index to be empty,for example String a= Integer.toString(type for int),then a.replace("your int","");